# How do I use Bioconductor and sangerseqR in R?

Tags: r, sequence, bioconductor

I want to use sangerseqR for .ab1 files. 
Searching for how to use it in R,

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
```

gives me a error message.

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
   cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
   unable to connect to 'bioconductor.org' on port 80
```

Is it compatible only with certain versions of R ? Or do I need to have some other packages installed before I can run Bioconductor ?

Comment: Works for me. Sounds like you're having a connection/firewall problem.

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine behing a certain company firewall? If so, try giving command `setInternet2()` first and the try the indicated source-command. If that works, you still need to install the package (`biocLite("sangerseqR"`), and load it into memory before you can work with it (`library("sangerseqR")`).

Comment: I tried 'run as administrator' option also, but I still get the same problem. I also tried copy pasting the script into R.

Comment: HI @JTT I managed to install Bioconductor using the commands you mentioned. But when I run
    library("sangerseqR") I get the error message : Loading required package: Biostrings
Error: package ‘Biostrings’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it. 
I am currently using R 3.1.2. Will it work on an older version ?

Comment: Do you have an old installation of the package? It most likely needs to be updated to work with the sangerseqR package. You can update the whole package library in R with `update.packages()`. If you specify to use also the Biocoductor repository, it will also update Bioconductor packages.

Comment: Rather than `update.packages()`, try `BiocInstaller::biocValid()` to check your installation, followed by `biocLite()`, responding that yes, you do want to update your old packages; Bioconductor uses a more rigorous versioning system than R alone, and has it's own repositories.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMorgan , I managed to solve it! :)